# C# WebService deletes the methods of the class my WebMethod returns

Tags: c#, web-services, class

**Hello**
I am working on a project for school and im using a webservice for it.
my problem comes when I return classes and try to access them on the website I refered to webservice to. 
At the third Web Method (`getAccountService`) I return a class (`AccountDetails`), this class has get and set methods which I want to use.
when I access it from my website by using `localhost.AccountDetails` I cant use any of these methods I do not have an option to pick any of the methods I wrote and its just like a useless class now.
I was really hoping someone can give me an answer on how to use these methods.
the webservice code is written below.

```
public class BankService : System.Web.Services.WebService {

public BankService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}

[WebMethod]
public Decimal GetBalanceService(int AccountID) {
    AccountService accService = new AccountService();
    Decimal decBalance = accService.getBalance(AccountID);
    return decBalance;
}
[WebMethod]
public DataSet GetTransactionsService(int AccountID)
{
    AccountService accService = new AccountService();
    DataSet dataset = accService.GetTransactions(AccountID);
    return dataset;
}
[WebMethod]
public AccountDetails getAccountService(string UserName, string Password)
{
    AccountService AS = new AccountService();
    AccountDetails account = AS.getAccount(UserName, Password);
    return account;
}

}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand the question but when a WebApi returns a result it's just JSON, not a Javascript class. There are no methods on it. Are you saying you are trying to call these methods from Javascript?

Comment: @JamesGaunt im developing in c# and for example I have a get method in the AccountDetails class which returns the Username of the account. when I try to use it it says that the localhost.AccountDetails which is the same class just in the webservice does not have this method and gives me an error like it does not exist

Comment: Can you show example code where you are calling the method and it is giving you an error?

Comment: @JamesGaunt its pretty hard to show since the project is connected with the class by the webservice but for example if I want to have access to the Username after creating the object which for example I call account. If ill use the command account.getUserName on the project the AccountDetails class is at itll return the string of the username but if ill use the same thing at the other project which is connected by the webservice and its finding the exact same class itll give me this error:

Comment: @JamesGaunt Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'AccountDetails' does not contain a definition for 'getUserName' and no extension method 'getUserName' accepting a first argument of type 'AccountDetails' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: So it's a compiler error - not runtime? This "AccountDetails" class is presumably some sort of proxy generated by a tool? If so it's just copying the shape of the data - not the full class behaviour? If you want it to be the same class maybe you can factor the class into a separate class library shared by both projects?

Comment: @JamesGaunt yeah thats the problem I  need it to have the full behaviour of the "AccountDetails" class because the WebMethod returns it without all its methods do you know a solution?

Comment: Yes you need to share the class itself. The tools will never build a proxy that includes all your methods. But you don't need a proxy if you put the class into a project that is shared between client and server.